# Proj4J not precise for EPSG:3857 transformations

Tags: java, proj

I try to convert some coordinates from "EPSG:31469" to "EPSG:3857" and back.

With the heavy framework GeoTools it seems to work pretty precise.

```
"EPSG:31469" - 5439627.33,          5661628.09
"EPSG:3857"  - 1573655.6648492748,  6636624.730959651
"EPSG:31469" - 5439627.330626475,   5661628.099510074
```

But I would like to use the lightweight library Proj4j (https://github.com/Proj4J/proj4j) which produces massive deviation:

```
"EPSG:31469" - 5439627.33,          5661628.09
"EPSG:3857"  - 1573659.9666159092   6603334.624358153
"EPSG:31469" - 5439626.576916553    5661585.491150079
```

Any ideas why this is the case?

My code:

```
import org.cts.crs.CRSException;
import org.osgeo.proj4j.CRSFactory;
import org.osgeo.proj4j.CoordinateTransform;
import org.osgeo.proj4j.CoordinateTransformFactory;
import org.osgeo.proj4j.ProjCoordinate;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CRSException
    {
        ProjCoordinate coord = new ProjCoordinate(5439627.33, 5661628.09);
        System.out.println(coord);

        ProjCoordinate target = new ProjCoordinate();
        CRSFactory crsFactory = new CRSFactory();
        CoordinateTransformFactory f = new CoordinateTransformFactory();
        CoordinateTransform t;

        t = f.createTransform(crsFactory.createFromName("EPSG:31469"),
            crsFactory.createFromName("EPSG:3857"));

        t.transform(coord, target);

        System.out.println(target);

        ProjCoordinate coord2 = new ProjCoordinate(target.x, target.y);

        t = f.createTransform(crsFactory.createFromName("EPSG:3857"),
            crsFactory.createFromName("EPSG:31469"));

        t.transform(coord2, target);

        System.out.println(target);
        System.out.println(target.x - coord.x);
        System.out.println(target.y - coord.y);

    }

}
```

Comment: Library feels a bit unmaintained. Perhaps you should try another lightweight java library https://github.com/orbisgis/cts instead.

Comment: The 3857 definition in the java version may be wrong. You're getting 3395 instead, maybe. That is,  it's using the wgs84 ellipsoid instead of a wgs84 sphere. That should still work on the round trip, just give you bad 3857 coordinates, so there's something deeper going on.

Comment: You are not alone with this problem: https://github.com/Proj4J/proj4j/issues/5 and https://github.com/Proj4J/proj4j/issues/3. You might try https://github.com/dwins/proj4j instead.

Comment: @AndreJ: Thank you. With the https://github.com/dwins/proj4j implementation it works precisely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to AndreJ!
The fork of proj4j at https://github.com/dwins/proj4j works precisely on EPSG:3857

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with your code, because in Python with [pyproj (python interface to PROJ4 library)](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj)

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
inProj  = Proj("+init=EPSG:31469")
outProj = Proj("+init=EPSG:3857")
x1,y1 =  (5439627.33,5661628.09)
x2,y2 =transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
x3,y3 =  transform(outProj,inProj,x2,y2)
print x1,y1
5439627.33 5661628.09
print x2,y2
1573657.37085 6636624.40597
print x3,y3
5439627.33052 5661628.09049
```

The core of the library [OSGEO Proj4J](https://trac.osgeo.org/proj4j/) is a port of the [​PROJ.4](http://proj4.org/) C library  and it is specified that:

> Status: Currently this library is still being created, and is not yet ready for download

There is a mailing list [The Proj4j Archives](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/proj4j/) and the last post is from Mars 2016 (for user30184)